# Write $4\cos x - 3 \sin x$ in the form $k\sin(x - \alpha)$ where $0 \le \alpha \le 360$

Tags: trigonometry

> Write $4\cos x - 3 \sin x$ in the form $k\sin(x - \alpha)$ where $0 \le \alpha \le 360$.

$4\cos x - 3 \sin x = k\sin(x - \alpha)$

=> $k(\sin x \cos \alpha - \cos x \sin \alpha)$

=> $k\cos \alpha \sin x - \sin \alpha \cos x$

Equating coefficients:

$k\cos \alpha = - 3$

$k\sin \alpha = 4$

$k = \sqrt{(-3)^2 + 4^2} = 5$

$\alpha$ is in the fourth quarter because $ \cos \alpha$ is positive and $\sin \alpha$ is negative.

$\alpha = \arctan\frac{4}{-3} = -53.1$

$\alpha = 360 - 53.1 = 306.9$

$4\cos x - 3 \sin x = 5\sin(x - 306.9)$

But the answer is $4\cos x - 3 \sin x = 5\sin(x - 233.1)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

$k\sin\alpha=-4,k\cos\alpha=-3\implies\alpha$ is in the third quadrant

See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation)

Comment: could you explain why $k \sin \alpha = - 4$ and $k \sin \alpha = - 3$.  I'm not getting this

Comment: @dagda1, As $$k\sin(x-\alpha)=\sin x(k\cos\alpha)+\cos x(-k\sin\alpha)$$  Now compare coefficients of $\cos x,\sin x$

Comment: this explanation works for me.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

$$4\cos x - 3 \sin x = k\sin(x - \alpha)$$
$$= k(\sin x \cos \alpha - \cos x \sin \alpha)$$
$$=k\cos \alpha \sin x - k\sin \alpha \cos x$$

Hence:
$$k\cos \alpha \sin x = - 3 \sin x$$
$$- k\sin \alpha \cos x = 4\cos x$$

so:
$$k\cos \alpha = -3$$
$$\color{red}{k\sin \alpha = - 4}$$

Comment: I don't get why $k \cos \alpha \sin x = -3\sin x$ when it is on the left hand side of the expression $k\cos \alpha \sin x - k \sin \alpha \cos x$ it would make more sense for me to make it equal 4

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is on the left or on the right, i.e. if it is the first or the second term in summation, as addition is [commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property). What does matter is the presence of the $\sin x$ factor. Sine and cosine are lineary independent, so one cannot replace the other; to make two expressions of the form $A\sin x+B\cos x$ and $P\sin x+Q\cos x$ equal independent on the $x$ value (assuming A, B, P and Q themselves do not depend on $x$), you need to make respective factors equal: $A=P$ and $B=Q$. In our case $A=k\cos\alpha$ and $P=-3$.

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$
\begin{align}
&4 \cos x − 3 \sin x \\
&= 5 \left( \frac{4}{5} \cos x - \frac{3}{5} \sin x \right) \\
&= 5 \left( \sin (\tan^{-1} (\tfrac{4}{3})) \cos x
          - \cos (\tan^{-1} (\tfrac{4}{3})) \sin x \right) \\
&= 5 \sin\left(\tan^{-1} (\tfrac{4}{3}) - x \right) \\
&= 5 \sin\left(x - (\tan^{-1} (\tfrac{4}{3}) - 180^\circ{}) \right)
\end{align}
$$